# array.map! starting at index other than 0

Tags: ruby

I am trying to mutate an array using map!, but starting index 1 and leaving index 0 unchanged:

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test[1..-1].map!{ |n| n += 2 }   
puts test
```

I would expect this to return

```
1
4
5
6
```

But it instead returns the unmutated array. Can someone explain why this does not work? Thanks

Comment: `test[1..-1]` returns a copy of that slice of the array. You then transform it and throw it away.

Comment: Your question has been answered, but one fix is `test[1..-1] = test[1..-1].map { |n| n += 2 }; test #=> [1, 4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 4):

```rb
test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test.map!.with_index { |n, i| i == 0 ? n : n + 2 }
# => [1, 4, 5, 6]
```

You can't use `test[1..]` because it creates a new array. I recommend you avoid mutated array operations if possible (https://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/avoid-mutation-functional-style-in-ruby/).

Comment: I suggest you delete or elaborate your last sentence, as "mutated array operations" is vague and neither the why nor "if possible" are clear. I'll delete this comment when I figure you've seen it.